# Remainder of $98!$ modulo $101$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My question is:

> What would be the remainder when $98!$ would be divided by $101$?

Though this question is very easy but I'm a little confused about my concepts.
I have found multiples of $2$ and $7$ in $98!$, thus eventually I found that it contains $14^{10}$ which is divisible by 101,so the answer would be $0$ as the remainder.

Is my answer correct?

Comment: Hint: Wilson's theorem.

Comment: By the way, since when  is $14^{10}$ a multiple of $101$?

Comment: In fact, $14^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod {101}$.

Comment: Sorry man, i had divided $14^{10}$ by $101$ in my scientific calc then everything went wrong

Comment: Oh, I see: dividing a $12$-digit number by $\sim 100$ on a calculator that shows $10$ significative digits always cuts away the fractionary part.

Answer (score 4):

$101$ is prime. It's a well-known fact that $(p-2)!\equiv1$ mod $p$. (The proof is that mod $p$, every nonzero number has a multiplicative inverse to pair with, except $1$ and $p-1$ which are each their own inverse.) So $99!\equiv1$ mod $101$. Find the multiplicative inverse of $99$, and multiply by it.

Answer (score 4):

We have $(98!)(99)(100)=100!$. Thus by Wilson's Theorem,
$$(98!)(-2)(-1)\equiv -1\pmod{101}.$$
Let $x=98!$. Then $2x\equiv -1\pmod{101}$. It follows that $2x\equiv 100\pmod{101}$ and therefore $x\equiv 50\pmod{101}$.

Comment: Sir, which property of modular arithmetic is used when we are write $(98!)(99)(100)\equiv -1\mod 101$ implies $(98!)(-2)(-1)\equiv -1\mod 101$ please reply

Answer (score 4):

Although the solutions here are outstanding, I want to share with you another approach.

Note that $98!\cdot99\cdot100\equiv(-1)(mod 101)$ from **Wilson`s Theorem**, we can get rid of the $100$ in the Left Hand Side of the equation (by *modular arithmetic*) and use the **Fermat Little Theorem**, as follows:

$99^{101-1} = 99\cdot99^{99}\equiv1(mod101)$

Using the fact that the inverse of $99$ is $99^{99}(mod101)$, we can begin our calculation from $99^{99}$ as follows:

$99^{99}=99\cdot(99^2)^{49} = 99\cdot4^{49}=99\cdot(4^7)^7=99\cdot22^7=99\cdot22\cdot22^6=99\cdot22\cdot(22^3)^2=99\cdot22\cdot43^2=57\cdot31\equiv50(mod101)$

Note that **Modular Arithmetic** is widely used here.

Comment: I would like to see you explain above, how "we can get rid of the 100".

Comment: its the modular -1 equivalence of 101 @311411

Comment: How does the factor of $98!$ relate to any of this?

Comment: The question is how 99 relates to mod 101. He makes all the problem here :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** By [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem), $$100! \equiv -1 \pmod {101} ;$$ on the other hand, $$100! = 100 \cdot 99 \cdot 98! .$$